# If $a$ is a real root of $x^5 − x^3 + x − 2 = 0$, show that $\lfloor a^6 \rfloor = 3$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

> If $a$ is a real root of $x^5 − x^3 + x − 2 = 0$, show that $\lfloor a^6 \rfloor = 3$.

Obviously since this is a 5th degree polynomial, solving it is not going to be possible (or may be hard). However I think that factoring it to get $x^5 − x^3 + x − 2 = (x^2-x+1)(x^3+x^2-x-2)$ will help. We know both roots of the quadratic are complex, so we need only focus on the cubic $x^3+x^2-x-2$. How can we use this to show that the real root $a$ of it has $\lfloor a^6 \rfloor = 3$?

Comment: Well the Intermediate Value Theorem says $a$ must be between $1$ and $2$.  So it's certainly plausible.

Comment: Note that it is not "obvious" that it cannot be solved. Wolfram gives a closed form.

Comment: Looks like a [duplicate](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814162/find-lfloor-alpha6-rfloor?rq=1)

Comment: May I ask what the source of this problem was?

Comment: There is a cubic formula btw...

Answer (score 1):

We have $\sqrt[6]{3} \approx 1.2009$ and $\sqrt[6]{4} \approx 1.2599$.  Let $f(x)=x^3+x^2-x-2$.  Then $f(1.2) \approx -0.032$ and $f(1.25) \approx 0.2656$.  So, $a$ must be between $1.2$ and $1.25$.

EDIT:  As I said in the comments below, I see no way of showing that there is only one root using only precalculus.  But, for completeness of my answer:  If there were two roots, then the Mean Value Theorem would imply that the derivative is $0$ between the roots.  But, $f'(x) = 3x^2+2x-1$.  The roots of this are $x=-1$ and $x=\frac{2}{3}$.  Using whichever method one likes, you can see that there is a local maximum at $x=-1$ and a local minimum at $x=\frac{2}{3}$.  And, both $f(-1)$ and $f\left(\frac{2}{3}\right)$ are negative.  So, there cannot be another root.

Comment: OP wants a synthetic proof without going into any numerical computation.

Comment: @Kf-Sansoo The OP doesn't mention that anywhere in their post.

Comment: And there might be another root.

Comment: @Hetebrij That's a good point to be mathematically complete with this question.

Comment: @Hetebrij I realized that as well.  But, at the precalculus level, I see no rigorous way of showing it is the only one.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 Maybe showing the second-derivative has the same sign (or doesn't) might help.

Comment: @user19405892 I have added a proof that there is only one root.  But, as I said, it doesn't stay at the precalculus level, which is what you tagged the question.

Comment: @user236182 No, it should not.  The OP has shown that we need only consider the $f(x)$ in my answer.

Comment: The fact that $h(x) = x^3 + x^2 - x - 2$ has only one root can be shown without calculus. We have $h(1/2) < 0$. For $x > 1/2$, $h(x)$ is increasing because $h(x) = x^3 + (x-1/2)^2 - 9/4$. Since $h(x) = x(x^2 + x - 1) - 2$, we have $h(x) < -2$ for $x \leq -2$. For $-2 < x \leq -1$, we have $|x^2 + x - 1| \leq 1$ and $|x| < 2$, so $h(x) < 0$. Finally, for $-1 \leq x \leq 1/2$ we have $|x| \leq 1$ and $|x^2 + x - 1| < 2$, so $h(x) < 0$ there.

Comment: Instead of $f(1.2)$ it should be $f(1.2009)$ or something slightly larger than $1.2009$.

Comment: I might be wrong, but you might be able to use [this theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1633846/proof-for-theorem-of-upper-and-lower-bounds-on-zeroes-of-polynomials) to show the upper bound, but you can't use it to show that there is any positive lower bound since it only works for negative lower bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=x^5-x^3+x-2$.

- First step. Differenciate the polynomial to obtain:
  $$f'(x)=5x^4-3x^2+1$$
  which has no zeros. Hence, $f$ has exactly one root.
- Second step. We have that $f(1)=-3<0$ and $f(2)=24>0$. Then the root lies in the interval $(1,2)$.
- Third step. Let $a$ be the root of $f$. We have
  $$a^6=a\cdot a^5=a(a^3-a+2)$$
  Now define $g(x)=x(x^3-x+2)$. Also differentating, we can see easily that $g$ is increasing in $[1,2]$, so now you have to try more values on $f$, to get finer bounds for the root. If we have that $l<a<u$ and $\lfloor g(l)\rfloor=\lfloor g(u)\rfloor$, then $\lfloor a^6 \rfloor$ is also the same.

Comment: A better third step: $a^6=2a-1+\frac{2}{a}$ (see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/814169/253273)). The derivative of the RHS is positive on $[1,2]$, so it is growing there from 3 to 4.

Answer (score 0):

Opposed to all of these answers, I will simply go ahead and solve the cubic:

$$0=x^3+x^2-x-2$$

Applying the cubic formula, I get:

$$x=\frac16\left(-2+\sqrt[3]{4}(\sqrt[3]{42+3\sqrt{177}})+\sqrt[3]{42-3\sqrt{177}})\right)$$

According to [Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%3Dx%5E3%2Bx%5E2-x-2).

Then I guess you would either do the floor function after getting it in decimal form or you could somehow take the floor function now.